# Outer measure, Caratheodory measure - proof

Tags: measure-theory

Let $m^*$ be an outer measure on a set $X:=[a, b]$. $A \subset X$ is a null set, i.e., $m^*(A) =0$. If $E \subset X$ is measurable, show that

$m^*(E\cup A)+m^*(E\cap A) = m^*(E)+m^*(A)$

I'm pretty sure I need to use the Caratheodory extension to show this, but not sure. Any help would be great!

Comment: Maybe you need to define what is $A$?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited it.

Comment: You know the outer measure is subadditive, right?  And monotone?  Won't that be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the equation is equivalent to $m^*(E \cup A) = m^*(E)$, because $A$ and thus $E \cap A$ are null sets. But this equation holds, since $m^*(E \cup A) \leq m^*(E) + m^*(A) = m^*(E) \leq m^*(E \cup A)$, using subadditivity and monotonicity. In particular, $E$ need not be measurable for this.