# For an outer measure $m^*$, does $m^*(E\cup A)+m^*(E\cap A) = m^*(E)+m^*(A)$ always hold?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $m^*$ be an outer measure on a set $X$. Is the following equality always true for every  $A \subset X$ and measurable set of $ E\subset X$ ?

$m^*(E\cup A)+m^*(E\cap A) = m^*(E)+m^*(A)$

**Note**: I read Another thing on 
[Outer measure, Caratheodory measure - proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371045/outer-measure-caratheodory-measure-proof) .
 but in the book of **Aliprantis** that is always true . thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$E$ being measurable gives, that for all $B$ 
$$ m^*(B) = m^*(B \cap E) + m^*(B \cap E^c)$$
applying this with $B = A \cup E$ gives
$$ m^*(A \cup E) = m^*(E) + m^*(A \cap E^c) \iff m^*(A \cap E^c) = m^*(A \cup E) - m^*(E) \tag 1$$
and with $B = A$
$$ m^*(A) = m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \cap E^c)\iff m^*(A \cap E^c) = m^*(A) - m^*(A \cap E) \tag 2$$
Now equate (1) and (2).