# Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set, let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be any set, then $m^*(A \cup E )=m^*(E)+m^*(A)$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E$ be a measurable set, let $A$ be any set, then if $m^*$ is the outer measure function, $$m^*(A \cup E )=m^*(E)+m^*(A).$$

Is this true? By subadditivity, we have $m^*(A \cup E )\leq m^*(E)+m^*(A)$. I want to show that $m^*(A \cup E )\geq m^*(E)+m^*(A)$ so the equality holds. I thought of applying the definition of measurable set $E$ by $$m^*(A \cup E )\geq m^*((A\cup E)\cap E) + m^*((A\cup E)\cap E^c)$$ but I'm not getting the right result. Any hint?

Edit: if we add the hypothesis that $E$ and $A$ are disjoint, then by measurability of $E$, we can simplify the above inequality by: $$m^*((A\cup E)\cap E) + m^*((A\cup E)\cap E^c) = m^*(E) + m^*(A).$$ Since if $A \cap E =\emptyset $ then $A\subseteq E^c$. What about this?

Comment: What if $A=E $?

Comment: Yep, seems like a counter example. This is false then? I might have misremembered/misread this question.

Comment: This might be true if $A$ and $E$ are disjoint though.

Comment: Sorry...misread the question. Is this what you're looking for?
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469027/for-an-outer-measure-m-does-me-cup-ame-cap-a-mema-alw?rq=1

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: It is not true in general. Counter-example: as @EclipseSun pointed out take $A=E$.   On the other, it is true if $A\cap E= \emptyset$  as the OP pointed out in the "edit" in the question.   In fact, it is true if $m^*(A\cap E)=0$, because then, since $E$ is measurable, $m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E^c)$.