# Is $\lambda^*(A \cap B) + \lambda^*(A \cup B) \leq \lambda^*(A) + \lambda^*(B)$ true for all sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $A$ and $B$ are measurable, then there is an equality: $\lambda(A)+\lambda(B)=\lambda(A \cup B)+\lambda(A \cap B)$. But is $\lambda^*(A \cap B) + \lambda^*(A \cup B) \leq \lambda^*(A) + \lambda^*(B)$ true for any sets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: What is $\lambda^*$? If $A,B$ are not measurable then is $\lambda^* (A)$ even defined?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy I think $\lambda^*$ is the outer measure, and a non-measurable set can have an outer measure.

Comment: @SL_MathGuy $A$ and $B$ are any sort of sets, even non-measurable. Outer measure defined even for non-measurable sets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For an outer measure $m^*$, does $m^*(E\cup A)+m^*(E\cap A) = m^*(E)+m^*(A)$ always hold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469027/for-an-outer-measure-m-does-me-cup-ame-cap-a-mema-alw)

Comment: @SL_MathGuy in this question one of sets is measurable.